# Imposible error occurs: grpc status = StatusCode.NOT_FOUND ,details = "Servable not found for request

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to serve a `keras.applications` model. Is not the first time I do so with help of a the `tensorflow-server` docker image, but I'm clueless as to why my code stopped working when I try with newly released model, Nasnet Mobile. The error I get is:

> _Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
>       status = StatusCode.NOT_FOUND
>       details = "Servable not found for request: Latest(nasnest)"
>       debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1544402081.202806558","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1036,"grpc_message":"Servable not found for request: Latest(nasnest)","grpc_status":5}"

I use the standard procedure to export the model

```
from keras import backend as K

K.set_learning_phase(0) # Deactivate train-only-layers like: batch norm and dropout
print(model.input)
print(model.output)

from tensorflow.python.saved_model import builder as saved_model_builder

export_path = 'export/nasnet/1' # should always end on int (model versioning)
builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)


from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants, signature_constants
from tensorflow.python.`enter code here`saved_model.signature_def_utils_impl import predict_signature_def
#from tensorflow.python.saved_model.signature_def_utils_impl import build_signature_def

in_tensors = dict()
out_tensors = dict()

sess =  K.get_session()

in_tensors['input'] = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_1:0')
out_tensors['predictions'] = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('predictions/Softmax:0')

prediction_signature = predict_signature_def(inputs=in_tensors,
                                            outputs=out_tensors)

# export the protobuf and its signatures
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess=sess,
                                    tags=[tag_constants.SERVING],
                                    signature_def_map={
        signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:prediction_signature})

builder.save()
```

Normal output shows up:

```
Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
Tensor("predictions/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 1000), dtype=float32)


INFO:tensorflow:No assets to save.
INFO:tensorflow:No assets to write.
INFO:tensorflow:SavedModel written to: export/nasnet/1/saved_model.pb

b'export/nasnet/1/saved_model.pb'
```

According to the [grpc docs](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/statuscodes.md), this type of error is not even supposed to be generated by grpc.Naturally, I mount the model into the docker container with:

```
docker run -d -p 8500:8500 \
    --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd)/export/nasnet/,target=/models/nasnet \
    -e MODEL_NAME=nasnet -e TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=0 \
    --name nasnet_tfserving \
    -t tensorflow/serving:1.10.0
```

There is only one model mounted in the container, with version 1. What could cause this kind of status code? The docker logs look normal:

> docker logs nasnet_tfserving 
>   2018-12-10 23:12:06.902367: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc:157] Building single TensorFlow model file config:  model_name: nasnet model_base_path: /models/nasnet
>   2018-12-10 23:12:06.904872: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:462] Adding/updating models.
>   2018-12-10 23:12:06.904932: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:517]  (Re-)adding model: nasnet
>   2018-12-10 23:12:07.006261: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:739] Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: nasnet version: 1}
>   2018-12-10 23:12:07.006484: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for servable version {name: nasnet version: 1}
>   2018-12-10 23:12:07.006539: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version {name: nasnet version: 1}
>   2018-12-10 23:12:07.006621: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/bundle_shim.cc:360] Attempting to load native SavedModelBundle in bundle-shim from: /models/nasnet/1
>   2018-12-10 23:12:07.006810: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: /models/nasnet/1
>   2018-12-10 23:12:07.257410: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
>   2018-12-10 23:12:07.557033: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: FMA
>   2018-12-10 23:12:08.726888: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:113] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
>   2018-12-10 23:12:09.814493: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:148] Running LegacyInitOp on SavedModel bundle.
>   2018-12-10 23:12:09.814631: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:233] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success. Took 2807935 microseconds.
>   2018-12-10 23:12:09.814818: I tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/saved_model_warmup.cc:83] No warmup data file found at /models/nasnet/1/assets.extra/tf_serving_warmup_requests
>   2018-12-10 23:12:09.815253: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:86] Successfully loaded servable version {name: nasnet version: 1}
>   2018-12-10 23:12:09.823923: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc:327] Running ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:8500 ...
>   [warn] getaddrinfo: address family for nodename not supported
>   [evhttp_server.cc : 235] RAW: Entering the event loop ...
>   2018-12-10 23:12:09.832156: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc:337] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8501 ...

Any comments??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that something was wroten wrong in your client code. The error said "Servable not found for request: Latest(nasnest)". But you started your tf-server using "nasnet" as your model name. Just change "nasnest" to "nasnet" in your client code.

Comment: Spot on man. I took me a while to figure out it was a typo on the model name. Is just that the error traceback was completely throwing me off. But lesson learned, next time something like this shows up models and paths is the first thing to double check.